# Nokogiri sax parsing the root attributes

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, sax, saxparser

Is it possible to parse and store an xml file root attributes in Nokogiri SAX parser?

How do one get the id-value and expires-value in the root-element?:

```
<root id="01" expires="2010-10-01">
  <aaa>Text</aaa>
  <bbb>Text</bbb>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nokogiri documentation gives you an example on how to parse xml using the sax parser and obtain what you need. Take a look here: http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/SAX/Document.html

Comment: Yeah I know, I know how to use all those methods. But there is no documentation on how to get a root element when sax parsing.

Comment: _start_element_ is called for every tag parsed. As for the root element, it'll be on the first call to that method. Try the sample code with your xml.

Answer (score 2):

Like @luis.parravicini said, *start_element is called for every tag parsed. As for the root element, it'll be on the first call to that method.*

So I did something like this:

```
class MyDocument < Nokogiri::XML::SAX::Document
  def initialize
   @infodata = {}
  end

  def start_element name, attrs = []
   @attrs = attrs
   @content = ''

    if name == 'rootname'
       @infodata[:id] = Hash[@attrs]["id"]
       @content = ''
     end
   end
end
```